# Find node in xml, despite how many nodes deep it might be

Tags: xml, parsing, powershell

This is a segment of an extremely large xml. I'm super confused as to how to get the results that I need from it.

```
<Task ID="269930118" Name="Name1" Active="0" NextEID="65" TT="COS" AR="0">
    <For ID="12">
        <If ID="13">
            <When>
                <Criteria>
                    <comp a="[OrigName]" test="MASK" b="53_Inbound_Daily_Account.txt"/>
                </Criteria>
                <UpdOrig Action="d" ID="45"/>
            </When>
        </If>
    </For>
    <If ID="37">
        <When>
            <Criteria>
                <comp a="[TaskStatus]" test="MASK" b="Success"/>
            </Criteria>
            <Email HostID="282198113" Subject="[TaskName] [TaskStatus]" Message="[TaskName] [TaskStatus]" AddressTo="email@email.com" UseDefRetryCount="1" UseDefRetryTimeoutSecs="1" ID="41" Type="SMTP"/>
            <RunTask TaskID="326261818" Wait="0" ID="51"/>
        </When>
    </If>
    <If ID="39">
        <When>
            <Criteria>
                <comp a="[TaskStatus]" test="MASK" b="Failure"/>
            </Criteria>
            <Email HostID="282198113" Subject="[TaskName] [TaskStatus]" Message="[TaskName] [TaskStatus]" AddressTo="email@email.com" UseDefRetryCount="1" UseDefRetryTimeoutSecs="1" ID="40" Type="SMTP"/>
        </When>
    </If>
</Task>
```

I need to add the task id to an arary if the following are true

```
comp.a -eq "[TaskStatus]"
comp.b -eq "Failure"
The email node exists right after the comp node. #pseudo code obviously
```

So the comp and email need to be within the same when node, but the when node may be any number of nodes deep into the xml in a given task. I'm super confused how to find these. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ids = @()

$xml = [xml](Get-Content .\Desktop\test.xml)

$xml.Task | ForEach-Object {

    if (@($_.SelectNodes('./*/When[Criteria/comp[@a = "[TaskStatus]" and @b = "Failure"] and (Email)]')).Count -gt 0) {
        #Criterias met. Add Task ID
        $ids += $_.ID
    }
}
```

Comment: you know what, I think I f*cked up. I used `//When` thinking it would be "anywhere below the Task node I'm searching from", but I think it search in different tasks aswell. I believe it's fixed now. :-)

Comment: Could be - I did not pay attention to details. You passed a right idea though.